# Use nameof() to get a attributepath for ModelState.AddModelError()

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-1.0

I like to use nameof() in my ASP.NET Core application when setting mvc errors using ModelState.AddModelError(). This reduces hidden errors since I pass the name of an attribute here. Compared to a string, this has the benefit that a compiler error is thrown when the attribute was renamed.

**Example**

```
class MyModel{
    public string Name{get;set;}
}
public class MyController:Controller{
    public IActionResult Test(MyModel model) {
        // Will hiddenly fail when "Name" is renamed to something else
        ModelState.AddModelError("Name", "The Name field is required!");

        // Better: Using the auto renaming feature of VS, this will be updated if "Name" was renamed
        ModelState.AddModelError(nameof(model.Name), "The Name field is required!");
    }
}
```

This works, until I have another entity:

```
class MyModel{
    public string Name{get;set;}
    public MyOtherModel OtherModel{get;set;}
}
class MyOtherModel{
    public string OtherName{get;set;}
}
```

Now I want to get the name of `OtherModel`. The problem: ASP.NET requires BaseClass.ChildClass pattern here, so `OtherModel.OtherName` in this example. Using the same logic like above:

```
public class MyController:Controller{
    public IActionResult Test(MyModel model) {
        ModelState.AddModelError(nameof(model.MyOtherModel.OtherName), "The Name field is required!");
    }
}
```

will just give me the name of the child attribute, so `OtherName` in this example. But I need `OtherModel.OtherName`. Is there a clean way to get this without building the string itself?

This would be possible doing something like this:

```
string actionName = nameof(model.MyOtherModel) + "." + nameof(model.MyOtherModel.OtherName);
```

But not a very clean and intuitive way imho.

Comment: I think building the string itself is your only option. `nameof` only gets the last name of your chain.

Comment: BaseClass.ChildClass is a little misleading since those terms refer to inheritance.

Comment: Write a helper method (or possibly an extension method) that wraps up the unsightly bits. Now your remaining code is clean.

Comment: @MattBurland you forgot `typeof` and get type name? ;)

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary: The OP doesn't want the type name, they want the property name `OtherModel.OtherName`. `OtherModel` is the name of property. It's type is `MyOtherModel`. Of course, they confuse the issue with their proposed solution because they do `nameof(model.MyOtherModel)` which obviously wouldn't work.

Answer (score 2):

As others have suggested, you will probably have to write your own method to do this. This is what I came up with using Linq.Expressions:

```
string NameOfMember(Expression<Func<Model, object>> accessor)
{
    string str = accessor.Body.ToString();
    return str.Substring(str.IndexOf('.') + 1);
}
```

You would then use it like this: `NameOfMember(model => model.MyOtherModel.OtherName)`

I'm not familiar with ASP.NET but you can change Model to any type you want, including object.

As a side note, you shouldn't repeat "The Name field is required!" in your code. Maybe you can include that in your helper method as well.